# Power BI Dataflow Updates But Dataset and Reports Do Not

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, dataflow, powerbi-datasource

I am in the process of creating a dashboard in power BI with multiple people. Currently I have 4 entities in a Dataflow that move to a dataset which are then visualized in reports. I recently added a column to one of my entities that I would like to show up in a report that is already created. However, despite the column being added to the entity (it shows up when I try to create a new report), it isn't displayed in the older report. How can I get my new column to display in an already created report?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the old report, go to the Query Editor and refresh the preview for it to pick up the new column.

[image]

You may have to go through the steps to make sure it is not removed, by for example reducing the columns down via a selection. When you create a new report you can see the column as it is getting the dataflow table structure with out any history in the query. Note this is not just for Dataflows, but for most types of connection where the structure changes, for example CSV, Excel etc.

Comment: These are made collaboratively within the Power BI web app (I think its called service), which doesn't have that option for reports.

Comment: You can download a copy of the report make changes (if you have permission) then reload it with the same name. Or get the report owner to make the changes. You can't do it in the service

Answer (score 0):

Check if the source data set is set to private by the person who published the report. Changing this might grant you access to the source dataset.